# Integral with trigonometric and dilogarithm

Tags: real-analysis, integration, special-functions

*The following integral can be characterised as an exotic one!*

Evaluate the integral:

$$\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \left ( \frac{\log  \left ( \tan x +1 \right )}{\log \tan x} - \frac{{\rm Li}_2 \left ( -\cot x \right )}{\log^2 \cot x} - \frac{\zeta(2)}{2 \log^2 \tan x} \right ) \, {\rm d}x$$

It was proposed by Cornel Ioan Valean, Romania.

I don't have any clue on how to attack this. Also, I don't think I can come up with any strategy that could work. So, I leave it entirely up to the community to come up with a clever approach.

**Edit:**  The name of the proposer is Cornel not Corel that I had written.

Comment: is there an expected closed form

Comment: The problem was proposed by Corel at a maganize. I believe mathproblems back in $2015$. So, I believe yes, there exists a closed form.

Comment: It's that weird that I'm not even sure about its convergence. Apparently is seems not convergent but probably it is. Maybe someone would start by noticing that

$$\text{Li}_2(-\cot(x)) = -\zeta(2) - \frac{\log^2(\cot(x))}{2} - \text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{\cot(x)}\right)$$

if it may have some relevance.. Meh.

Comment: Thanks for sharing Alan . That's a start .

Comment: I contacted the proposer. He said that the closed form of the problem is pretty simple. Shock !! So, any other thoughts?

Comment: Start by changing the variable $u=\tan x$. This could simplify some things since you have compositions of functions with $\tan$ and $\cot$.

Comment: Thank you all for the participation. The author claims that the answer is $\frac{3 \pi}{8}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$
I = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \left(\frac{\ln(\tan x+1)}{\ln(\tan x)} -\frac{\text{Li}_2(-\cot x)}{\ln^2(\tan x)} - \frac{\zeta(2)}{2\ln^2(\tan x)}\right) dx \\
= \left(\int_0^\frac{\pi}{4} + \int_\frac{\pi}{4}^\frac{\pi}{2}\right) (\ldots)dx = I_1 + I_2
$$
On $I_2$, perform the substitution $x\to\frac{\pi}{2}-x$ to obtain:
$$
I_2 = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \left(\frac{-\ln(\cot x+1)}{\ln(\tan x)} -\frac{\text{Li}_2(-\tan x)}{\ln^2(\tan x)} - \frac{\zeta(2)}{2\ln^2(\tan x)}\right) dx
$$
Summing $I_1$ and $I_2$, we get:
$$
I = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \left(\frac{\ln(\tan x+1) - \ln(\cot x + 1)}{\ln(\tan x)} -\frac{\text{Li}_2(-\tan x)+\text{Li}_2(-\cot x)+\zeta(2)}{\ln^2(\tan x)}\right) dx
$$
By the [inversion formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm#Dilogarithm), we have:
$$
\text{Li}_2(-\tan x)+\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{-\tan x}\right)+\zeta(2) = - \frac{1}{2}\ln^2(\tan x)
$$
Also as :
$$
\ln(\tan x+1) - \ln(\cot x + 1) = \ln\left(\frac{\tan x+1}{\cot x + 1}\right) = \ln\left(\tan x \ \frac{\tan x+1}{1 + \tan x}\right) = \ln(\tan x)
$$
We can substitute in:
$$
I = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \left(\frac{\ln(\tan x)}{\ln(\tan x)} -\frac{-\frac{1}{2}\ln^2(\tan x)}{\ln^2(\tan x)}\right) dx = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\frac{3}{2} \ dx = \frac{3\pi}{8}
$$

Comment: Wow !! Thanks !!